# Django max_length of another model attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models, maxlength

I want to have the integer value of one model attribute be the max_length of another model attribute like mentioned below "capacity = models.IntegerField(**max_length=Concerthall.capacity**)".

```
class Concerthall(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=254)
    capacity = models.IntegerField()
    employees = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Events(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=254)
    capacity = models.IntegerField(max_length=Concethall.capacity)
    timeFrom = models.DateTimeField()
    timeTo = models.DateTimeField()
    concerthallName = models.ForeignKey(Concerthall, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
```

Maybe it is also working with validators but I searched for several hours and wasn't able to find any solution to this.

Comment: `IntergerField` has no attribute `max_length`

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you add a better explanation?

Comment: Why would you need to do this if you can always access the hall capacity by `my_event.concerthallName.capacity`? Why do you need to store the capacity twice?

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. The point it that the capacity of a Concerthall is static e.g. 400 people. But the capacity of a certain event is not. It could be 350 or 200 but definitely not over 400.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a different approach, doing the validation in the models [`clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method:

```
class Events(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=254)
    capacity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    timeFrom = models.DateTimeField()
    timeTo = models.DateTimeField()
    concert_hall = models.ForeignKey(Concerthall, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def clean(self):
        if self.capacity > self.concert_hall.capacity:
            raise ValidationError(
                'the capacity of the event cannot exceed the capacity of the hall')
```